# How can I export a keyword list from Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, keywords

In Google Analytics, I've been following several tutorials to export a list of keywords, but something is going wrong.  This is what I try:

1.) click traffic sources
2.) click keywords
3.) Click Export
4.) Click CSV

The resulting file shows two columns.  Column A is dates.  Column B is visits.  I am trying to export a file so that Column A is keywords and Column B is visits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scroll down a little. The keywords are below the dates.

[image]

Comment: Wow.  I'm feeling a little silly about this one.  Thanks.

Comment: :) I actually thought for a moment that you might have found a bug in GA...until I scrolled down a bit.